# Problemas al usar los booleanos en python

Tags: python, numpy

Pongamos que tengo una matriz 4x4, y quiero obtener mediante booleanos las esquinas de esta matriz, resultando en una matriz de 2x2. He intentado hacerlo con un código muy simple, pero no devuelve lo que quiero, y no se el por qué. (He conseguido hacerlo, pero de una forma mucho mas larga y creo que se tiene que poder de otra manera). Adjunto código

```
import numpy as np 
bool = np.array([True, False, False, True])

mat = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

print(mat); print(bool)
print(mat[bool,bool])
```

Así he conseguido que funcione pero es largo e innecesario a mi opinion

```
import numpy as np
bool = np.array([True, False, False, True])

mat = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

mat2 = mat[bool,:]
print(mat2[:,bool])
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que usar `booleanos` para abordar este problema te está complicando encontrar una solución. Mi propuesta:

```
mat = np.arange(16).reshape(4, -1)  
esquinas_indices = [  
    [0, 0],
    [0, -1],
    [-1, 0],
    [-1, -1],
]
esquinas_indices = np.array(esquinas_indices).T.tolist()   
mat[tuple(esquinas_indices)].reshape(2, -1) # Matriz de 2x2    
>> array([[ 0,  3],[12, 15]])
```

De esta manera, independientemente del tamaño de la matriz, y de que sea o no cuadrada, podrás encontrar siempre las esquinas.